# Redux Saga: How to wait for spawn and call to complete without blocking parent call

Tags: javascript, redux, redux-saga

I'm trying to add a redux saga function but I can't get the chaining right

```
const randomDelay = () => parseInt(Math.random() * 500)
const a = function*() {
   yield spawn(b)
   yield call(c)
}
const b = function*() {
   yield delay(randomDelay())
}
const c = function*() {
   yield delay(randomDelay())
}
const d = function*() {}
```

- I want to call `a` which will spawn `b` and call `c`.
- When `c` is complete I want `a` to become unblocked and complete.
- When `b` and `c` both complete I want to call `d`

From what I can tell there isn't a way to do this.  `all` or `fork` will block `a`

To get around this for now I have `c` called first and a combo of `b` and `d` spawned after but that means `b` and `c` can't be running at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

To do this you need a separate signalling mechanism. I would use a `channel` for this.

- `a` first creates a channel
- `a` spawns `dScheduler` passing the channel
- `a` passes the channel as an argument to `b`
- `b` does a `put` to the channel at the end
- `a` does a `put` to the channel at the end (when `c` finishes)
- `dScheduler` does two `take`s on the channel and then calls `d`

The code would look something like the following:

```
import { delay, channel } from "redux-saga";
import { spawn, call, put, take } from "redux-saga/effects";

const randomDelay = () => parseInt(Math.random() * 500);
const B_OR_C_COMPLETED = "B_OR_C_COMPLETED";
export const a = function*() {
  const bcCompletedChannel = channel();
  yield spawn(dScheduler, bcCompletedChannel);
  yield spawn(b, bcCompletedChannel);
  yield call(c);
  yield put(bcCompletedChannel, B_OR_C_COMPLETED);
};
const b = function*(bcCompletedChannel) {
  yield delay(randomDelay());
  yield put(bcCompletedChannel, B_OR_C_COMPLETED);
};
const c = function*() {
  yield delay(randomDelay());
};
const dScheduler = function*(bcCompletedChannel) {
  yield take(bcCompletedChannel);
  yield take(bcCompletedChannel);
  yield call(d);
};
const d = function*() {
};
```

Here's a CodeSandbox with console logs added and the delay lengthened to make it easy to verify the behavior:

[image: Edit y2yx3rp7rv]

The relevant part of the Redux Saga documentation is [here](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/advanced/Channels.html). Specifically the section near the bottom called "Using channels to communicate between Sagas".

Answer (score 0):

Not as elegant as https://stackoverflow.com/a/54140525/4453205.

Also my answer assumes `a` does the job of just calling `b` and `c`(or two tasks only).

```
import { delay } from "redux-saga";
import { all, cancel, put, takeEvery, spawn, call } from "redux-saga/effects";

const randomDelay = () => parseInt(Math.random() * 500);

export function* startTasks() {
  let completed = yield call(a);

  if (completed) {
    yield call(d);
  }
}

const a = function*() {
  let b_finished = false;
  const b = function*() {
    yield delay(randomDelay());
    yield put({ type: "B_DONE" });
    b_finished = true;
  };

  const c = function*() {
    yield delay(randomDelay());
    yield put({ type: "C_DONE" });
  };

  const taskB = yield spawn(b);
  yield call(c);
  yield cancel(taskB);
  return b_finished;
};

const d = function*() {
  yield delay(randomDelay());
  yield put({ type: "D_DONE" });
};

export function* watchStartTasks() {
  yield takeEvery("START_TASKS", startTasks);
}

export default function* rootSaga() {
  yield all([watchStartTasks()]);
}
```

Comment: Cancelling `b` is not part of the desired behavior.

Comment: Yes you are right. I have mentioned in the answer `Also my answer assumes a does the job of just calling b and c`, so cancelling `B` would mean cancelling `A`.