# Which type is runSaga(,secondparam,) is expecting and how to make one?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux-saga

I'm trying to write test of a saga that handles login. Here is my code below and the issue I'm running into:

```
const fakeStore = await runSaga(
 {
   getState: () => ({...state}),
   dispatch: (action) => dispatchedActions.push(action)
 },
 apis.user.login, // this where the issue is from
 payload
).done;
```

`Tslint` error message:

```
Argument of type '(user: Authentication) => Promise<IUserResponse>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Saga1<Authentication>'.
  Property 'next' is missing in type 'Promise<IUserResponse>' but required in type 'Iterator<any>'.
```

Here is `apis.user`

```
apis{
 user: {
  login: (user: Authentication):Promise<IUserResponse> =>
   axios.post('/api/login', user)
     .then((res) => res.data)
     .catch((res) => res.data || { message:"" }),
 }
}
```

I don't get how to make that `Saga1` type. I looked into the type definition and here is how it looks like:

```
export function runSaga<A, S, T1>(
  storeInterface: RunSagaOptions<A, S>,
  saga: Saga1<T1>,
  arg1: T1): Task;

Saga1<T1>

type Saga1<T1> = (arg1: T1) => Iterator<any>;
```

Comment: please recommend any other library that you ever tried and think can help, e.g: **redux-saga-test-plan** ,

Comment: the second param needs to be a saga, not sure about typescript - in flows.js you can do `import type {Saga} from 'redux-saga` and then use it like `function* saga(): Saga { }`

Comment: I've figured out the issue. My second arg was the api rather than saga. And I had to mock the api function as well.

@MartinKadlec thanks you comment gave me a clue, in typescript `redux-saga` exposes `SagaIterator`

Answer (score 1):

The `Saga1` type refers to a [generator function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*). These functions return an iterator when they are called, but you don't need to worry about that aspect since ReduxSaga calls the function and interacts with the iterator. You can see an example of using `runSaga` in [this CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/y2yx3rp7rv) which I created for [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54137804/redux-saga-how-to-wait-for-spawn-and-call-to-complete-without-blocking-parent-c/54140525#54140525).